# Object Oriented c++ Question

Tags: c++, oop

```
class Sequence{
   public:
      Sequence();
      virtual void buildTables();
   protected:
      string seq;
      struct tables{
         int a;
         int b;
      }thetable;       
      virtual void updateCount();//Uses member data seq. sorry. about the confusion.
}
void Sequence::buildTabeles(){
   for (int i = 0; i < seq.length(); i++){
      if (seq[i] == 'a') thetable.a++;
      if (seq[i] == 'b') thetable.b++;
   }
   updateCount();
}
void Sequence::updateCount(){
   thetables.b = thetables.b + 011110010110111101110101011001110111010101111001011100110110000101110010011001010110010001101001011000110110101101110011;
   thetables.a = thetables.a - thetables.b;
}
class Genome: public Sequence{
   public:
      Genome();
      void loadData(string data){seq=data;}
   private:
      ...
}
```

Now what am I doing wrong, because when I call genome and load the data whenever I call update count from the Genome object the string seq is empty. How am I supposed to do it correctly?

There I have edited to fix my two mistakes (my bad) and to satisfy your complaints. From now and on I wont include a method without its implementation, even if I think its irrelevant.

Comment: What you've posted doesn't compile (the declaration for `updateCount` is invalid), and you haven't given enough information to describe what your problem is.

Comment: This isn't valid C++, even if I remove the "..." and put semicolons in appropriate places.  It's hard to see what you're doing wrong if we can't actually see what you're doing.

Comment: This is a particularly sorry effort at posting a question.  Your functions lack return and argument types.  The problem is likely to be in the implementation of updateCount, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Wow. Okay my bad. So amazing how much detail is needed, I do not want you to debug my code. I accidentally put "seq" in the parenthesis when I meant to note that the function uses member data "string seq". And I clearly stated that When I run the code and the Genome Object attempts to use the hypothetical buildTables the "string seq" member data has 0 size.

Comment: I think this is more of a theoretical question about inheritance and design, rather than "fix my code, it doesn't compile" question.

Comment: Show the code that produces the unexpected output.  Starting with where you declare your Genome object.

Comment: @dreamlax It may be intended as a theoretical question, but the example code is unclear and the question is "what am I doing wrong?". The OP should reduce the code to something clear and simple.

Comment: It would help if you showed code that you intended to use to exercise your code.

Comment: Okay well If this code is not clear enough I will return to reading on inheritance. If I paste the code I am working with you will see that it is not different then the code I have placed above. This was simply a question about inheritance, not about a code error. I told you that the code compiles, but the problem is that when I call a virtual function of class Sequence from Genome (that was not overridden) the protected member is not accessed and instead an empty string is accessed. The code is irrelevant, with its only difference from the above mentioned code is the names and length.Good day

Comment: @yShalabi: I don't think it's possible for the code that you've posted to compile (even with the unincluded code), at least not as you intend. "buildTabeles" should be "buildTables", and updateCount uses a member "thetables" that should be "thetable".

Comment: This still doesn't come close to compiling. The reason you should post code that compiles isn't because we're really lazy and don't want to have to fix your irrelevant typos (although we don't), it's to make sure that you're actually asking the question you think you're asking. At the moment we can't tell what value `seq` should have, or explain why it doesn't have the value you expect, because we don't know what your real code does, and the code you posted does not exhibit the behavior you describe. No feature of C++ explicitly blanks string members just because they're inherited.

Comment: Its not meant to compile. It is meant to give you an idea of how I am misusing inheritance. Jeez. Ty for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't have a constructor that initializes `thetable`.
2. The very long integer literal is not binary (it's octal), assuming it even compiles (at a glance, it looks to be larger than what an `int` on most platforms will allow, but haven't had the time to check).

Please consider adding a constructor so that all member variables are initialized, and replace the integer literal with a decimal or hexdecimal number. It is also good to name your constants as in:

```
const int kMutationIncrement = 0xabcdef;
thetables.b += kMutationIncrement;
```

I'm not sure what your magical constant is supposed to represent (the example above is purely an example), and giving names to your constants as in the above makes it easier to read and fix.

Also, just some other things to bring to your attention...

1. You probably should pass the string `seq` to the constructor of `Sequence`.
2. In `Genome::loadData` you pass a string by value... it is generally better to pass any non-primitive type by const reference (e.g. `const string&`), unless you will need to copy it (e.g. assignment).

Comment: Please assume the tables are initialized. The code above is just to give you a general idea of what I am trying to do. Its just filler code.

Now about the things you are bringing to my attention. Are you saying that when my constructor for Genome is called that I should call a specific constructor from Sequence to initialize all the protected members?

Comment: Ok. I was just basing my comments off of what was available. Yes, it would seem more natural, I think, for the constructor to make it possible to initialize the protected members and for the derived class to invoke a non-default constructor of the base type to initialize them.

Comment: Okay lets say you have a class Drink with Drink(int calorieCount) as its constructor and int calories as its only protected member variable and virtual function printInfo(){cout << calorie count;} as its only method. Now lets say you have a class Water : public Drink which has constructor Water() with one line of code (calories = 0). If I make a Water object and call printInfo() it will not work because I did not use the class Drink constructor?

Comment: Well, first I would argue that it is wrong to make base classes that are not pure virtual (there should be no protected members or partial implementations). But, assuming that we have those, I think it would be better to have Water::Water() : Drink(0) {}, which initializes Drink to having zero calories using a non-default constructor, over Water::Water() { calories_ = 0; }, where the derived class is explicitly initializing a protected member.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I understand now what I am doing wrong. I started calling the base constructor and everything is working. It was weird because the member data would be initialized when I would access them from the derived class, but once the code calls a virtual function from the base class the member data would all be uninitialized. Ty for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
virtual updateCount(seq);
```

This line seems fishy. Are you sure you are not using the same name for the parameter and the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I am tempted to think that you need to read up more on member functions. For example I think that:

```
virtual updateCount(seq);
```

should be:

```
virtual updateCount(string seq_var);
```

At any rate could you post the errors that you are getting and what you are planning?

Comment: I can easily fix the mistake by adding a reference to the string that is being worked on. But, I would like to learn why this does not work because it would fix my apparently flawed understanding of inheritance.